# volatile test did not meet its happen-before feature in JLS

Tags: volatile, happens-before

Run main

```
public class ThreadTest {
volatile int p = 0, q = 0;
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread writeThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    p++;
                    q++;
                }
            }
        };
        Thread readThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    //p should not be less than q
                    if(p<q){
                        System.out.println("happen before violation p = " + p + ";q = " + q);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        writeThread.start();
        readThread.start();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(2);
        writeThread.interrupt();
        readThread.interrupt();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new ThreadTest().test();
  }
}
```

output

happen before violation p = 736;q = 827
happen before violation p = 4635;q = 4657
happen before violation p = 6421;q = 6440
happen before violation p = 8719;q = 8803

Answer (score 0):

You should read *p* AFTER *q* for being sure that their values are in "not less than" order:

```
int q_value = q; // Read 'q' once
int p_value = p; // Read 'p' AFTER q
if(p_value < q_value) // ... happens-before violation
```

In that case **volatile** modifier is required only for *q*, and it can be omitted for *p* without constraints' violation.

In you original code nothing prevents the compiler from reading *p* BEFORE *q*. So readThread can see *p* value from 736-th iteration of the writeThread, but see *q* value from 827-th iteration.
Or readThread can see *p* value from the beginning of the 100-th iteration(that is, p=100), but see *q* value from the end of that iteration(that is, q=101).